# How to avoid 'two children with the same key' warning when inserting in object in React/Redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

So I have a list of users in my Redux state that looks like this:

```
const users = {
  byId: {
    "1237": { id: "1237", name: "Fred", email: "fred@example.com" },
    "1235": { id: "1235", name: "James", email: "james@example.com" },
    "1234": { id: "1234", name: "John", email: "j.doe@example.com" },        
  },
  allIds: ["1237", "1235", "1234"]
};
```

And a React component that renders them in a table:

```
render() {
  const { users: { allIds, byId } } = this.props;
  return allIds.map((id) => {
    const user = byId[id];
    return (
      <tr key={ id }>
        <td>{ user.name }</td>
        <td>{ user.email }</td>
      </tr>
    );
  });
}
```

I make an API request to fetch the data and I update the state in Redux:

```
const usersLoadFulfilled = (state, action) => {
  const ids = [...state.users.allIds];

  const { data } = action.payload.data;

  const byId = data.reduce((acc, user) => {
    ids.push(user.id);
    return { ...acc, [user.id]: user };
  }, state.users.byId);

  return {
    ...state,
    users: {
      ...state.users,
      byId,
      allIds: ids,
    },
  };
};
```

The JSON response I get is ordered by reverse chronological order (most recent at the top, oldest at the bottom), which is how I need to display the results.

The problem comes when I make a second API request. The above function gets called and I get many of these warnings in the browser's console:

```
Warning: flattenChildren(...): Encountered two children with the same key, `1234`.
Child keys must be unique; when two children share a key, only the first child will be used.
```

The keys map to a unique id in the database, so they *are* unique.

How do I avoid this warning?

What are the best practices when rendering a table of data that might get more results prepended to the top?

Comment: It seems like that your second AJAX request does not update `allIds` in your reducer, and just adds them again. Can you provide the code for the reducer?

Comment: one of the ways , pass 2nd argument to map and use it as a key : `allIds.map((id , index ) => {
    return (
      <tr key={ index }>
      </tr>
      )}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem seems to be in your reducer:
You take allIds that you have in the state already and make a new array out of them and the ids, that are fetched from the backend. This causes duplication of ids in the state and causes the error when you are mapping over the allIds in the render method.

```
const usersLoadFulfilled = (state, action) => {
  const ids = [...state.users.allIds]; // <-- old state: ["1237", "1235", "1234"]

  const { data } = action.payload.data;

  const byId = data.reduce((acc, user) => {
    ids.push(user.id); // <-- here is a chance to push duplicated ids in there
    // if the second response has the same users, so in the end you have ["1237", "1235", "1234", "1237", "1235", "1234"]
    return { ...acc, [user.id]: user };
  }, state.users.byId);
```

One way to fix it is to do the check if the id is already there before pushing, but this might mess up the sorting you need.

Comment: That was it. I stopped pushing the id twice, and that fixed my issue—thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to add the key as unique identifier?

Try something like this:

`key={value.id + value.somethingelse}`

Comment: I just tried `key={ id + user.email }`, the warning is still there

Answer (score 0):

The problem you are trying to add all the second request result ids to the previous request result ids
so ids must be initialised with an empty array `[]`

```
const usersLoadFulfilled = (state, action) => {
 const ids = [...state.users.allIds]; // change this
 let ids = []; // to this
```

Comment: Using array index as a key for react components is risky and should be avoided, unless you don't have any other option, since it can cause unexpected behaviour, when list is updated and react does reconciliation. More info here: https://medium.com/@robinpokorny/index-as-a-key-is-an-anti-pattern-e0349aece318